# PHP Form data not inserting into MySQL database

Tags: php

HTML FORM

```
  <form class="form" method="post" action="process.php">
    <h4 class="form-heading">Please New Enter Customer Information</h4>
    <label for="inital">Inital:</label>
     <select id="inital" name="inital" required="required">  
        <option value="mr">Mr</option>  
        <option value="ms">Ms</option>  
        <option value="mrs">Mrs</option> 
        <option value="prof">Prof</option>      
        <option value="dr">Dr</option>    
    </select>  
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required="required" >
    <label for="lastname">last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required="required">
    <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" required="required">
    <label for="landline">Landline:</label>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Landline" name="landline">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="required">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" required="required">
    <label for="postocde">Postal Code:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" name="postcode">
    <label for="accessibility">Accessibility:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Accessibility Needs" name="accessibility" value="">

    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Enter</button>
```

process.php

```
    <? php

require( '../connect_db.php' ) ;

$inital = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[inital]);  
$firstname = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[firstname]); 
$lastname = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[lastname]); 
$mobile = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[mobile]); 
$landline = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[landline]);
$email = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[email]);
$address = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[address]);   
$postcode = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[postcode]); 
$accessibility = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST[accessibility]); 

$query = "INSERT INTO `customer` (inital, firstname, lastname, mobile, landline, email, address, postcode, accessibility) VALUES ('$inital','$firstname', '$lastname','$mobile','$landline','$email','$address','$postcode','$accessibility')";

/* execute the query, nice and simple */
$sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error);

 ?>
```

I have tried alternatives too but to no satisfaction like not including `$inital =($_POST[inital]);` Instead putting right into INSERT INTO section but that  still does not help either.

It either prints out the whole code on screen or blank. I've looked at similar problems on here and on forums all them seem to present the issue differently and when i change it suit the so called answer it still does not work!

My other page that lists all the tables using the following connection required statment works works fine so there is no problem with connection to the database but at this moment just cannot insert content. Grr

Comment: "prints the whole code" e.g. your php code shows up instead of being executed? that's a server configuration issue... Your $_POST keys also need to be quoted: `$_POST['mobile']` and the like. PHP will politely (in most cases) pretend the quotes are there, but spit out warnings.

Comment: `<? php` This will case error. And, if you don't have short-tags enabled, **will not** be treated as PHP code.

Comment: Show connect_db.php also.

Comment: in query you forget to put "set" "INSERT INTO `customer` SET..."

Comment: Why do you need SET for INSERT?

Comment: @mohammad totally bogus.

Comment: Thanks Macr B. for your prompt reply, What shall i do to make it work using local system XAMPP Version: 1.8.1 with PHP 5.4.7 installed.

Comment: Daninis Abols, Jonathon Reinhart Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `<?php # CONNECT TO MySQL DATABASE.

$sql = @mysqli_connect ( 'host', 'user', 'password', 'database' )

# Otherwise fail gracefully and explain the silly error. 
OR die ( mysqli_connect_error() ) ;

# to Set the lovely encoding to match PHP script encoding.
mysqli_set_charset( $sql, 'utf8' ) ;

?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

change `<? php to <?php`

and then add quotes to your post data values. `$_POST[inital] to $_POST['inital']`

and for your information i would do `isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : '';`

you still need to check post value before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `<?` php tag. it should be `<?php`